# Is there a single word for "無用"

Tags: word-choice

I wish to know is there in Chinese language a single word for "無用"?

Comment: Which "無用" are you talking about? Japanese? Cantonese? Zhuangzi?

Comment: @Semaphore - If it's in Cantonese it would be `冇用` so it's definitely not Cantonese.

Comment: The same as Useless T

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Do you mean "single character"? 无用 _is_ a single word.

Comment: Word can means both 字 or 詞.  It is obvious Brian is looking for a single 字 for the term 無用

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if by 无用 you mean useless and by one word you mean one character then I would recommend:

**废** it has a lot of meanings but specifically here it contains the meaning:

> waste; useless; disused; superfluous in ²fèizhǐ -*ABC*

Answer (score 3):

It depends why that thing is considered "無用".

For example, if it is considered redundant, you can say "贅".